# How do I use a template literal in a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testcase

I am writing a test which clicks on certain filters and I notice some discrepancies between browsers. For example On major browsers(Chrome, Firefox, Safari) there are check boxes  shown exactly in this format: Checkers, Cheese, Salsa, Butter. When I run the test on IE11 those strings are lower case and because it is lower case, my test is failing.  To combat that I was hoping  to use regular expressions. The function I am using to click those checkboxes is reusable.

I am puzzled because I am trying to pass the string in the regular expression but the test fails. I then went on to create a template literal and someone pass the string in the regular expression that way and the test still failed. My question is, is there a smarter way to pass in a string variable into a regular expression?

The filterPage looks like:

```
     export default class OrderHistory {
      constructor() {
          this.filter = Selector(
                ".filterCheckbox"

}

async selectFilter(text) {
    await t.click(this.filter.withText(`/${text}`/i));

}
```

The test page looks like:

```
 test(“click the cheese filter”, async t => {
   const cheeseFilter = Cheese;

   await filterPage.selectFilter(cheeseFilter);
```

});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Comment: "[I]s there a smarter way to pass in a string variable into a regular expression"? Yes. [`new RegExp(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: You can use `new RegExp(text,"i")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description) constructor might do the job if you need to build the regex dynamically, since it can also **accept a string**.

```js
new RegExp(text, 'i');
```